# Bar Graph with Multiple y Axes with different values

Tags: android, android-studio, graph

I am developing an `android app` in which I need to draw bar graph with multiple y-Axis values as image attached.

[image]

I tried [MpAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library but not able to design the same bar chart.

Answer (score 1):

these are 2 graphs placed one above the other.Place one graphs y axes to left and other graphs y axes to right. There are methods to change position of Y axes in all libraries for drawing graphs.

Comment: Do you have any other references which matches my requirement?

Comment: And i want y axis with different values.

Comment: they are totally 2 different charts so list of thier y axes are different .make 2 different instances of your graph and set them on 2 different layouts . Just place those layouts one above the other and set y axes of one to left side and other y axes to right side. I have implemented this using achartengine. Use : renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.RIGHT, 0);

Comment: You develop the same graph that i  need. This is kind of combined chart right.

Comment: i have developed a combination of bar chart and line chart using achartengine. Combined chart is a name given by MPAndroidChart library but i have not used it . I think it does not allow different y axes values. Instead of using combined chart use 2 different chart and just place one above the other.

Comment: I designed the same by combine the graphs, its working fine on mobile and tablet. But in tablets Graph and all the text are getting blurred.

Comment: can u paste a snapshot of the same?

Comment: This is the screenshot http://prnt.sc/ctd9gl you can clearly see the text is getting blurred.

Comment: The text appears to be clear for me ..only the distance between y axes and labels is less ..is that your concern ?

Comment: Text is clearly seen but its blur. Yes that is also the concern

Comment: for that you can use methods like renderer.setXLabelPadding(),renderer.setXLabelAngle() etc.

Comment: Which Class is handling complete UI part for designing the graph?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125687/discussion-between-mansi-salvi-and-mamta-kaundal).